# How to display X and Y coordinates

Tags: c#, mouse, coordinates

Currently I have the following code to get the mouse position, which works fine with no errors. Now though, I need to say the coordinates in 2 labels I have set up. The label names are "Xcoord" and "Ycoord" if you need to use them in a sample code. Thanks!(:

```
private void pictureBox_View_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x, y;
    x = e.X;
    y = e.Y;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Convet [`Int32.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tostring.aspx) and set to [`Label.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.text%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property:

```
pictureBox_View.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
                            {
                                Xcoord.Text = e.X.ToString();
                                Ycoord.Text = e.X.ToString();
                            };
```

**UPDATED**: You can use Timer for global using in your form:

```
var timer = new Timer{Interval = 30};
timer.Tick += (s, ev) =>
                    {
                        Xcoord.Text = Cursor.Position.X.ToString();
                        Ycoord.Text = Cursor.Position.Y.ToString();
                    };
timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Xcoord.Text = e.X.ToString()` and `Ycoord.Text = e.Y.ToString()`

**Edit**

```
private void pictureBox_View_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x, y;
    x = e.X;
    y = e.Y;
    Xcoord.Text = x.ToString();
    Ycoord.Text = y.ToString();
}
```

`Xcoord` and `Ycoord` must be labels on the form that this event handler is defined in

Comment: No luck, is there anything I need to put in the section where there's all the "Using" stuff? (Sorry for noobness, started today). I don't have any errors, it's just not showing the coordinates.

Comment: So you are expecting the coordinate values to show up when you move the mouse over the pictureBox? or just on Mouse Down?  Are you sure that the event is triggering?  Put a break point in it and see if it is hit....

Comment: Nope, no using stuff. Assumed you were only attempting to capture coordinates on mouse down as per your posted event handler.

Comment: I think I'm just totally screwing up my code. I just want to move my mouse around my program, and for it to be updated in the labels in real time.

p.s There is a web page in my program, I don't know if that will make the coordinate system different.

Comment: I think you are handling the wrong event,you need the MouseMove event and not the MouseDown event

Comment: Alright, I switched my code to MouseMove now. So right now I have the same code, I just changed "MouseDown" to "MouseMove". Still not seeing my coordinates, though.

Comment: Is it doing what you need it to now?

Comment: No. Still not getting any coordinates. Do I need to set the Text to anything special in the labels?

Comment: Did you register the event handler?, pictureBox.MouseMove += pictureBox_View_MouseMove;

Comment: meirrav, whenever I put that in my code, it is just an error. I've been putting it above the "private void pictureBox_View_MouseMove etc" So where would I put that?

Comment: mlorbetske, there is a web page in the program, but there is a little area off to the side where there's no web page. It's not working for either part of the program.

Comment: What meirrav is saying is to put that line after InitializeComponent in the constructor of the form

Comment: Actually, go to the design view, click on your picture box, go to properties, select the events tab, double click on MouseMove, copy the code inside the above method into the thing it generates for you

Comment: mlorbetske, I just put it after InitializeComponent, and I'm getting an error saying: The name "pictureBox" does not exist in the current context"

Comment: merirrav, I was putting it in the wrong place. Once I put it in the wrong place I got the following error: "pictureBox" does not exist in the current context"

Comment: What's the name of your PictureBox control and is it on the form you put the line in the constructor for?

Comment: I think I've screwed the pooch on this one. I got the code on a forum, but now I'm thinking I don't even have a picture box.. I have a web page.

Comment: If you'd like we can get on Skype and I'll help you through it

Comment: mlorbetske, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what the problem is, just save them in the labels text property.

```
pictureBox.MouseMove += pictureBox_View_MouseMove;

private void pictureBox_View_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Xcoord.Text = e.x.ToString();
    Ycoord.Text = e.y.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Add ToString() to your values - can't assign `int` to `string`